# Python return subset of multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have the following Python multi dimensional list

```
oldList = [['a', '0', '1', '2'], ['b', '3', '4'], ['c', '5']]
```

How can I get each list within this multi d list?

```
i.e. newList1 = ['a', '0', '1', '2'] 
     newList2 = ['b', '3', '4']
     newList3 = ['c', '5']
```

Answer (score 5):

You already have each sublist. They're in the list. If you want the first one, you could use

```
oldList[0]
```

or if you know there will be 3 sublists and you want all of them, you could use

```
a, b, c = oldList
```

or if you want to iterate over them, you could use

```
for sublist in oldList:
    do_stuff_with(sublist)
```

Iteration is probably what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use values unpacking:

```
oldList = [['a', '0', '1', '2'], ['b', '3', '4'], ['c', '5']]

newList1, newlist2, newlist3 = oldList
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use use indexing with oldList:

```
newList1 = oldList[0]
newList2 = oldList[1]
newList3 = oldList[2]
```